# IronPython in VisualStudio 2012

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ironpython, ptvs

Is there support IronPython in VisualStudio 2012? I not found IronPython project in templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: http://pytools.codeplex.com/. Support was added in PTVS 1.5 RC [Sep 2012].

Answer (score 4):

Python Tools for Visual Studio, [PTVS 2.0 Beta or 1.5 RTM](https://pytools.codeplex.com/), both have built in templates for developing against IronPython.  To use these templates you'll need to first install IronPython.
Check out the [installation page](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation) on PTVS which has instructions on how to install interpreters.

Answer (score 2):

By default, no. Presumably [PTVS](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) will before too long.

Comment: PTVS now has support for VS2012 via 1.5RC.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like PTVS (Python Tools for Visual Studio) 2.0 will not install IronPython by default. I had success installing [PTVS 2.0 Alpha](http://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/72638) and [IronPython 2.7.3](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/81726) from its separate project page into Visual Studio 2012.